# Replace article with div with a button that will stay and can toggle between article and div content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want with jQuery when I click the button to toggle the content between the article and the div.
jQuery so far, but its not working as intended.
Thats all i have, i will appreciate if you guys could guide me.

```js
   $('.gal').on('click',function(){
      if($('article').css('display')!='none'){
       $('#vnav').html($('#vnav').html()).show().siblings('div').hide();
        }else if($('#vnav').css('display')!=='none'){
          $('#vnav').show().siblings('div').hide();}
     });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="gal">Gallery</button></div>
    
    <article>some content inside</article>
    
    <div id="vnav" style="display:none;">
     <ul id="horizontal"> 
      <li><img src="images/1.jpg" width="782" alt="" height="440" /></li> 
      <li><img src="images/2.jpg" width="782" alt="" height="440" /></li> 
      <li><img src="images/3.jpg" width="782" alt="" height="440" /></li> 
      <li><img src="images/4.jpg" width="782" alt="" height="440" /></li> 
      <li><img src="images/5.jpg" width="782" alt="" height="440" /></li> 
     </ul> 
    </div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So when you click the button the div's content should go into the article?

Comment: Or should the content swap?

Comment: The article is the static content, onclick the article should dissappear and the div content should appear on article's place

Answer (score 3):

You just need to write this code to toggle between `article` & `div` on button click.

`$('.gal').on('click',function(){
  $('article').toggle();
  $('#vnav').toggle();
});`

Comment: Thanks this were very helpful :) i haven't thought about it :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this https://jsfiddle.net/2Lzo9vfc/170/

**JS**

```
var show = true;

$('.gal').click(function() {
 if(show == true) {
   $('article').hide(200);
   $('#vnav').show(200);
   show = false;
 } else {
   $('#vnav').hide(200);
   $('article').show(200);
     show = true;
 }
});
```